# Push div after content on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar on page which should have background color all the way to the right side so it can't be inside container (or it can?). I am struggling with positioning it so that the content and sidebar don't overlap. 
But my question is how can I push the sidebar on smaller screens after content? (without having duplicate content)
I am trying to mess a little as possible with Bootstrap code so that it doesn't break somewhere later

https://jsfiddle.net/vzoz53zm/

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 35%;
  max-width: 300px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #sidebar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

<div id="sidebar">
  <p>
    SIDEBAR
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move your HTML for the side bar after the container, and add `top: 0;` to your `#sidebar` styles. At the moment your sidebar appears first in the document, you have removed it from the document flow using absolute positioning, but when you insert it back in (setting it to `position: relative;`) it goes back into the document above the `.container` div.

See fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vzoz53zm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add top:0 styles to the sidebar styles, it will meet the requirement.